# JavaScript: Passing different count of parameters to callback function

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, parameter-passing

Every time I want a function run with callback, I have to change my parameter from `(par1,par2)` to `(args)`. Is there any way to keep my parameter name?

Here is my code now:

```
function runwithcallback(callback, ...args) {
  callback(args);
}

function Boo(args){
  let par1 = args[0];
  let par2 = args[1];
}
function Foo(args){
  let par1 = args[0];
  let par2 = args[1];
  let par3 = args[2];
}

//normal call
Boo(["1","2"]);
Foo(["1","2","3"]);

//call with callback
runwithcallback(Boo,"1","2");
runwithcallback(Foo,"1","2","3");
```

And what I want:

```
function runwithcallback(callback, ...args) {  
  callback(args);
}

function Boo(par1, par2){
} 
function Foo(par1, par2, par3){ 
}

//normal call
Boo("1","2");
Foo("1","2","3");

//call with callback
runwithcallback(Boo,"1","2"); 
runwithcallback(Foo,"1","2","3");
```

Comment: You can use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or spread syntax.

Comment: Spread the args into the callback: `callback(...args);` ?

Comment: Just a very subjective observation: instead of doing any of that I'd pass an actual callback function: `runwithcallback(() => Boo("1", "2", "3"));`

Comment: to @NickParsons I succeed by using `callback(...args);`. Thanks, can you use formal answer to let me select you to best answer?
@ChrisG yes,I also use lambda with short function.